# Joda Time returning yyyyww for Jan 1, 2016 as 201653

Tags: java, jodatime, week-number

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyww");
dateTimeFormatter.print(new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 1, 1).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC))
```

returns 201653

Why is it 53 week of 2016 rather than 2015?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the **week-based-year (symbol x)**, not the year of era (symbol y). See also the [pattern syntax used by Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) which deviates from that of `SimpleDateFormat` or Java-8. So the solution should look like:

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("xxxxww");
String s = f.print(new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 1, 1).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC));
System.out.println(s); // 201553
```

Answer (score 0):

Because January 1st was Friday. And in that case, that week counts as last week of 2015, and the first week of 2016 will start on first Monday (January 4th).
That is implemented in accordance with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) standard:

> There are several mutually equivalent and compatible descriptions of week 01:
>   - the week with the year's first Thursday in it (the formal ISO definition),
>   - the week with 4 January in it,
>   - the first week with the majority (four or more) of its days in the starting year, and
>   - the week starting with the Monday in the period 29 December – 4 January.

Comment: I agree it should be counted as last week of "2015" but not "2016"!!

Comment: Oh, that. Well that is separate data. year IS 2016, isn't it? :D